# Which type of In App Purchase should be used for 100s of product with same price?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have created an app in which I have category of images and every category has unlocked images. There are around 10 categories and each category has 50 locked images. User should be able to pay $0.99 for each image through In App Purchase. Since the price of each image is same so can I use the same product identifier for each image and make that Consumable? Or I will have to add 500 product Identifiers and make them Non Consumable? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would create some kind of In-App currency which could be bought with In-App purchases (consumable) and could be used to buy the images. To prevent the user from losing already purchased images I would upload them to iCloud. If the user removes the app from it's device he will still be able to access the image on other device or on the same device after reinstalling the app.

Another advantage of this solution is that you can give away images/IA-currency for free, which wouldn't be possible with the alternative solution. Giving away could be very useful for marketing (for ex. giving away a free image when inviting friends to use the app).

*Only weak point is when the user manually deletes the images from iCloud or the user disabled the iCloud feature the images will be lost when the user removes the app. But I ignore that issue and assert that that's the users fault. If you want to workaround that issue you would have to setup a central server and log which user has bought which image.*

Comment: By currency means like stars or points? And User will purchase the points and on purchasing the coins the image will be unlocked? Is it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am meaning.